# DateTime Local time zone to UTC and UTC to some other selected timezone conversion in Android

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

I am developing an android application. In my app I stored my logged-in local date time in preference and showing in the user profile page. After some of days I changed my mobile timezone as Australia. Now I need to convert my existing local date time to Australia timezone date time and display in profile page. Is it possible. Show me the code snippet. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In short, describing your requirements and asking "show me the code" is not what StackOverflow is about.  Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
String inputText = "2017-05-17 15:50:00";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);

    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a");
    // Adjust locale and zone appropriately
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(inputText);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(outputText);
```

Try this code.. it may help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did upto this level. But I need to convert from this UTC to current timezone of my device which I was changed. It may be Perth, Adelaide, Melbourne, Tokyo and so on.

Comment: just try this code once and check the result.. u will get time according to your need.

Comment: Expected result not arrived.
Your input : 2017-05-17 15:50:00
Date after UTC timezone added : Wed May 17 09:55:00 GMT-06:00 2017
Date after formatted : May 17, 2017 9:55 AM .My requirement is change this UTC time to some other selected timezone datetime value.
For Example : 
My current local timezone is IST and stored the date time in preference and also displayed in the app page. If suppose I moved to some other foreign country and changed my timezone in device, the date time seems like incorrect. I need to convert my existing local date time into my current current time zone date time.